# Cannot use REPLACE syntax on shared hosting

Tags: mysql, syntax, privileges

I create a mysql database using CPanel on a shared hosting server ... i have given privileges of CREATE, UPDATE, DELETE, INSERT to the user, what privilege should i give to use the REPLACE syntax .... available privileges (as you might already know)... ALTER, CREATE ROUTINE, CREATE VIEW, DROP, INDEX, LOCK TABLES, SELECT, UPDATE, CREATE, CREATE TEMPORARY TABLES, DELETE, EXECUTE, INSERT, REFERENCES, SHOW VIEW ... but i could not find the REPLACE privilege ... as this is my first experience on online server .... i have no clue please help ... :)

Answer (score 4):

Quoting the [**manual page for `replace`**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman//5.5/en/replace.html) :

> To use `REPLACE`, you must have both the `INSERT` and `DELETE` privileges
>   for the table.

Which makes sense, considering that replace can do either a simple `insert`, or a `delete` and then an `insert` *(if the first insert failed because a duplicate-key error occured)*.

Comment: You can almost always use `INSERT IGNORE ... ON DUPLICATE KEY` instead of `REPLACE INTO`.

Comment: i have already given INSERT and DELETE privilege to the user before posting this..